# Driver issues Sapphire Nitro+ RX 470 8G

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I recently replaced my old broken card with a Sapphire Nitro+ RX 470 8G. At the beginning it seemed to work after I removed some old drivers etc. But once i restarted the computer, no signal were coming from the GPU. I have then reinstalled windows 10 to eliminate any errors from it. At the first run it worked, but when restarting the computer same error as before occurred (no signal from GPU). When I then tried to remove all the drivers that had been installed and then restarted, the graphic card seemed to work, but when restarting same thing as before happens.

To summarize the things I know

- Remove drivers -> shutdown computer -> insert GPU -> turn on computer (some drivers are automatically installed here ) -> GPU emits signal to display -> restart computer -> No signal

Comment: Get the correct drivers from [AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/auto-detect-tool) & install before rebooting. Report back.

Comment: When using the auto-detect driver, it only finds the integrated gpu (probably since thats where the display is connected to). Have tried installing drivers from this page http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows+10+-+64.

Comment: Problem solved after I updated bios